# VBA how to solve issue when excel create a new sheet map 1 but is counting further with map2, map 3 , etc

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing a problem when "in the same active session" of "1 workbook" I have to export some (several) sheets into different directories by ceating different workbooks by a button and code I wrote. The problem is that excel is giving the new maps automaticly a name , for example when first workbook has been created it will automaticly call it map 1 , the second workbook will called map 2 , the third ect.. Is there no way to let VBA alsways refer to the new created map without refering to map 1 for example? In the code processes I have to refer to the new map (in each worksheet of my workbook) but I had to name all of them map 1 for now (in my codes).. It is working well when I close the main workbook and reopen again, but that is not the way it should work. Can I enter some DIM settings and refer to the new created workbook please? I believe this question is not asked this specific earlier. Thnx...

I tried to simplify the code to make it a little understandable.
Practically I should flip over from Thisworkbook to WbNew.
I hope I can make my question clear enough.
I try to put some suggested settings too.

```
Sub Testing Macro()
Dim wbNew as Workbook


' Testing Macro
'How can I command to switch over workbooks without counting the excelnumbers of workbooks?
'switching and savings are not working at the moment.
'we always start from Thisworkbook.
' This workbook is the original workbook
'Wbnew should be the new created Workbook (each new created and active Wb of course) , the new Wb will be closed after process


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SPECIFIC").Activate    
Range("A1:AS291").Select
Selection.copy
Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SPECIFIC").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Select
Selection.copy

Wbnew.Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste   
Application.CutCopyMode = False

WbNew.Activate
--> some formulas here

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = ""
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With

Application.PrintCommunication = True
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    -->some page setting here
End With

Application.PrintCommunication = True

WbNew.SaveAs Filename:= _
ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Path\" & ".xlsx"
FileFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Please share your code with us so it will be easier to assist you with improving your code to cope with this (it doesnt sound difficult, but without the code it becomes too much guessing). Nevertheless I have tried to address this problem in general terms in my answer below

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! That was lightning fast! I first go to try if I can do some changes in order to see if that would help me out. I think I go the idea. I will resume this threath later if the problem persist. Thanks again.

Comment: Now I posted the code, but It is giving some errors when referring (reopening) to Wbnew (new created workbook) and saving is in error too. :-(

Comment: ah you havent actually linked a specific excel to the wbNew object. You will need a line like `Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook`  or where you add a new workbook change the line into `Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add`

Comment: Hi I added the link you suggest in the code above, but now it is creating 2 workbooks? :-) And get stuck later :-) Do I do something wrong?

Comment: OK, just tested to activate  ThisWorkbook first and now it is working. Many Thanks voor the ideas!!!!!!

Comment: it is creating with workbooks add 2 workbooks at the same time at the moment. Go test first some other combinations :-(. This is also overwrriting my Original workbook at the moment. It seems that switching over to thisworkbook and wbnew is still a problem.

Comment: If you now have 2x workbooks.add then indeed you create 2 workbooks. Delete the line where you create the "third workbook" that isnt useful.  Use F8 to debug your code line by line and see what each line does, put a break (F9) at the start of your Sub to stop the code there and use F8 to debug.

Comment: I gave 2 options in my comment earlier, so you should CHOOSE ONE, not use both ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29227/discussion-between-user2151190-and-k-b)

Comment: Exellent work!!!!!!!!! You learned me something new today!! THANK YOU VERRY MUCH!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a new `Workbook` (which you call Map) is created the is an `Workbook` object that can be captured.

As you can see the new `Workbook` will get the focus so what you can do after `Copy`ing the single `Sheet` into a new `Workbook` you capture that new object by:

```
Dim wbNew as Workbook

'... OTHER CODE

Sheet1.Copy 'Or similar code you use to separate your Sheet
Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
```

Or in your revised code:

```
Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
```

Then you can do with this object what you want, rename/`Save`, `Close`, add more sheets, manipulate its content, retrieve its `Name`:

```
MsgBox wbNew.Name
wbNew.Save
wbNew.Close
```

Good luck